# What is the equivalent of '$ heroku config' for local rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the equivalent of '$ heroku config' for local rails server

I want to list the environment variables on my local rails server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENV` is a hash with all of the environment variables.  From the console you can check it out by just typing:

```
ENV
```

To get a specific var (SHELL is an example):

```
ENV["SHELL"]
```

I'd recommend something like figaro to help you manage these between local and Heroku:  https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Answer (score 0):

Loose equivalent would be:

```
env
```

(you would do it from the command line, of course)